# Error 500 in Django WEB APP on IIS (TimeOut )

Tags: python, django, iis, web-development-server, iis-10

I have a web app (DJango/ReactJS) that works perfectly on localhost, but after deploiment on IIS 10 some requests (http post) stops after 30, 40sec with state 500 (u have some inputs then a function gonna treat and calculate then return a resullt).

- i tried to change the timout (from 120 to 12000) in IIS settings but no diffrence !
- i checked the logs on IIS, on windows's event viewer but no errors detected !
- i found one error in httperr folder : 443 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle
- Is it mandatory to reset IIS after any changes and how long it takes to be able to use the apps in IIS again without problems ?

any sollution ?

Comment: Try changing MinFileBytesPerSec from 240 to 0, and change ConnectionTimeout from 120 to 600, restart IIS after setting.

Comment: thanks @JennyDai , i'll try to change MinFileBytesPerSec but do i have to restart IIS ? because the clients are using the apps and i don't know how long it takes to normaly use the apps again

Comment: i've read in an article that the changes gonna be applied automatically without retarting ,@JennyDai (i don't know if it's true )

Comment: Can't help you with IIS specifically, but I've seen this issue when a Python web framework is deployed in local development mode.

Comment: @AgostBiro and what was the sol in that case ?

Comment: @AlaliJessika to run it release mode. Not sure how that works in Django, but you should be able to find something in Google